# How can generate thumbnail with timestamp with ffmpeg

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, position, timestamp, thumbnails

I am working with ffmpeg.

I made some thumbnails with ffmpeg command like below.

```
ffmpeg -ss 600 -i input.mp4 -s 420x270 -f mjpeg vframes 1 output.jpeg
```

but it is just plane photo.

What I need is some thumbnail like youtube thumbnail which has time positions

on picture.

If you have any challenging ideas, please let me try.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same, I can tell you this won't work I spend many hours ob implementing that. You need to get the length of the video and take several screenshots e.g. all 3 seconds. Than you can build a stripe and show a small part of the image as the preview.

Comment: so you mean if I want to do something like this, I should extra job, right? for instance, bitmap redraw or something...